# how can I get angle of aruka mark?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, aruco

I need to get angel of rotation Aruko Marker
For example: x = 45* y = 56* z = 15 *
I use one marker to orient the robot in space
I am trying to use ArUco marker detection in OpenCV to calculate the angle of the marker compared to the camera plain.

This is my code, that I nead to add?

```
import numpy as np
import time
import cv2
import cv2.aruco as aruco
dist=np.array(([[-0.58650416 , 0.59103816, -0.00443272 , 0.00357844 ,-0.27203275]]))
newcameramtx=np.array([[189.076828   ,  0.    ,     361.20126638]
 ,[  0 ,2.01627296e+04 ,4.52759577e+02]
 ,[0, 0, 1]])
mtx=np.array([[398.12724231  , 0.      ,   304.35638757],
 [  0.       ,  345.38259888, 282.49861858],
 [  0.,           0.,           1.        ]])
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX #font for displaying text (below)
def detect():
    # camera: c270
    mtx = np.array([[8.2177218160147447e+02, 0.0                   , 3.4694289806342221e+02],
                             [0.0                   , 8.2177218160147447e+02, 2.4795144956871457e+02],
                             [0.0                   , 0.0                   , 1.0                   ]])
    dist = np.array([4.4824308523616324e-02, -7.4951985348854000e-01, 3.7539708742088725e-03, 8.8931335565222442e-03, 3.7214188475390984e+00])
    rvec = np.array([])
    tvec = np.array([])
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_6X6_250)
    parameters =  aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
    corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = aruco.detectMarkers(gray, aruco_dict, parameters=parameters)
    rvec, tvec, x = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, 0.04, mtx, dist)
    rmat, jacobian = cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)
    if (corners != []): 
        rvec, tvec, _ = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, 5.4, mtx, dist)
    print(rmat)
    return frame, rvec, tvec
#num = 0
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    h1, w1 = frame.shape[:2]
    newcameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(mtx, dist, (h1, w1), 0, (h1, w1))
    dst1 = cv2.undistort(frame, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)
    x, y, w1, h1 = roi
    dst1 = dst1[y:y + h1, x:x + w1]
    frame=dst1
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_6X6_250)
    parameters =  aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
    dst1 = cv2.undistort(frame, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)
    #Use aruco The detectmarkers() function can detect the marker and return the ID and the coordinates of the four corners of the sign board
    corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = aruco.detectMarkers(gray,aruco_dict,parameters=parameters)
#    If you can't find it, type id
    if ids is not None:
        rvec, tvec, _ = aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners, 0.05, mtx, dist)
        detect()
        (rvec-tvec).any() # get rid of that nasty numpy value array error
        aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(frame, corners) #Draw a square around the mark
        for i in range(rvec.shape[0]):
            cv2.drawFrameAxes(frame, mtx, dist, rvec[i, :, :], tvec[i, :, :], 0.03)
            cv2.drawFrameAxes(dst1, mtx, dist, rvec[i, :, :], tvec[i, :, :],0.03)
        ###### DRAW ID #####
        cv2.putText(frame, "Id: " + str(ids), (0,64), font, 1, (0,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
    else:
        ##### DRAW "NO IDS" #####
        cv2.putText(frame, "No Ids", (0,64), font, 1, (0,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
    # Display result frame
    cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:         # Press esc to exit
        print('esc break...')
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
    if key == ord(' '):   # Press the spacebar to save
        filename = str(time.time())[:10] + ".jpg"
        cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
```

I try all, all, and i dont know what I nead to do.